# OS X System Congiuration Settings, Set in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, operating-system, network-programming

What would be the best method for configuring OS X Network Proxy preferences in Objective C? If anyone has any code examples that would be very helpful.

- Also -

I have been searching all around the interwebs and can't seem to find a good source for setting OS X System preferences/settings with Objective C. Anyone have any good sources?

Answer (score 2):

Setting Mac OS X System Preferences is widely discouraged since it decentralises [and therefore defeats the purpose of] System Preferences. There are very few applications for Mac OS X that modify system behaviour/configuration legitimately, at this point I can't even think of one.

The actual proxy information may differ between each version of OS X, but on my 10.6 system it is contained within the file:

```
/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

This is just a simple XML property list file that can be parsed and regenerated using the [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. Note that the password for proxies are stored elsewhere (I think you'll need to use the standard [Keychain Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html) to obtain the password). The file above is read-only by non-root users, and read-write only by root, therefore if you actually do want to edit the contents of this file, your application must obtain root privileges. Apple has a [programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html) on gaining these privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just to explain myself better, I was curious about setting system prefs with Obj-C for system deplyment purposes. I have used Applescript and shell for this in the past, and was wondering if Obj-C provided me with any more elegant options.

Comment: `NSPropertyListSerialization` link dead. New link [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspropertylistserialization).

Answer (score 2):

A quick look here ...:

http://osx.hyperjeff.net/Apps/apps?f=preference

... reveals ...

> AMPreferencePane - Cocoa classes for creating preference panes
>
> SS_PrefsController - Preference window Cocoa class
>
> sysprefs - Utility to change/view the system network preferences
>
> UKPrefsPanel - Cocoa helper class for Preference windows

Maybe there's also sample code referring to the command line tools networksetup(8) and systemsetup(8), which may perhaps be similar to ...

> ncutil - Network configuration utility  (src: yes)

For deploying purposes have a look at:

> InstaDMG - Tool for the modular creation of deployment packages
>
> DeployStudio - Complete workstation install/restore utility

Hyperjeff's Cocoa Literature List has a networking section as well!

HTH